# How to protect a list in SharePoint?

Tags: list, permissions

I have created a list in SharePoint as a database for my access application. Since data is confidential and everyone is having access to SharePoint how can I prevent data so anyone can not access apart from authorized users only?

I'm struggling with this since last few days, would be great if someone provide solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to handle permission is create a SharePoint access group name as **access database group** with **Read** or **Contribute** permission as per your your need -  add all the authorized users there, then as Rune suggested in previous answer, go to the list permissions setting page, stop inheritance to break the parent permission structure, remove all users and groups from there only keep the group which you just created ie **access database group** and a dedicated user or probably can create another new group only for the people who will manage this list who should have **Full Control** permission.

Comment: Sure, I cant see option create group. Could you please let me know what needs to be done. Should I approach to super user of the site for this or is there any other way to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to **List Settings**, then **Permissions for this list**, you will see how the permissions for the list is configured. It is probably inheriting permissions from the site (that is the standard setup).

What you want to do is to click the button **Stop inheriting permissions**. This will leave the permissions intact, but any changes to the permissions to the site will not be pushed to the list.

The next step is to remove any users or groups that should not have access to the list and make sure that all the users that *should* have permissions have the right permission levels.

Comment: Hi Rune, thanks for your response. I have searched for this option but after entering to list settings I can only see options under permission:   **Delete this list 
  
Apply label to items in this list or library 
  
Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings**. Is it because of I have limited access to sharepoint?

Comment: Yes, it would seem so.

Comment: Thank you Rune!